# Backup to SD card in kit kat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, backup, external-sd

Is there a backup program that will allow me to back up directly to my SD card in Kit Kat without an internet connection?

I currently am forced to back up to the internal storage {after clearing space} then copying to the SD card, then deleteing the copy on my internal storage.  this wastes *much* time and effort.  My phone storage is only 2.8GB free, but my SD card has 28.0GB free.

Comment: What exactly are you currently backing up, and how? Are you using some 3rd-party app or tool?

Comment: I purchased MyBackup Pro a while back. I have backups from that going back over a year.  I would be willing to pay for an ubgrade, but they refuse to fix the software.

Comment: There is a very good method of making backup even for non-rooted devices but it will make backup on a PC. See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28315/225285)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're wanting to back up, but most backup applications on the Play Store will do this for you.  Examples are MyBackup Root, Titanium Backup, and Helium.

EDIT:  Scratch that.  As mentioned by Izzy in the comments below, you must be rooted for these apps to work, as there is a..."feature"...in Android 4.4 KitKat that prevents "rouge" SD Card access: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY/UsxMYwu02z0J)

Comment: Not without root, sorry – not on Kitkat (except maybe on Huawei devices). You forgot about the mess Google created with the SDCard permissions on Kitkat, I'm afraid ;)

Comment: UGH I FORGOT ABOUT THAT UGH I HATE KITKAT (I fixed that as soon as it happened and haven't worried about it sense, so I completely forgot haha)

Comment: "If we cannot force manufacturers *not* to use SDCards – we can at least care for them being unusable". A Nexus has no such, thus the UX on it isn't affected. And no warning in advance, which is the biggest thing to blame. </rant>

Comment: Actually you do NOT need root.  Doggcatcher writes to the SD card on my unrooted phone.  You simply must use a space on the card that you (each app) owns.

Comment: These answers are incorrect.  Apps CAN WRITE TO THE SD CARD ON UNROOTED PHONES.  The only res G eiction is that they must write thier own locations.  Doggcatcher writes many GB to my SD card every week.

Comment: @RobertFarley that is correct, however, backup apps are considered to write arbitrarily when moving devices and ROMs. It's a known issue with many prominent apps, such as Titanium and MyBackup

Comment: @RobertFarley while apps may be able to write to the SD card without root access, apps *cannot* read the root folder of internal storage without root access, only the public folders. Thus, it will never be a complete backup.

Answer (score -2):

KitKat all but broke any usefulness of SD cards. The solution is to export your backup to your PC. The sad thing is this is easier than using your SD card. Use a program like SnapPea or one of the many others like it.

To root most KitKat devices, you can download towelroot APK. Do a quick Google search for it. Go to settings, allow apps from other sources. I think it's in developer options, been a while since I needed it. Install with the Package installer. Open and click make it rain. Now you will either reboot and be rooted or nothing will happen. Install SuperSU. Update binaries, install BusyBox. Install your choice of backup apps.